# How to populate a column's value based on two other column's values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
|  DEL_ID   |   CP_ID   | ID  | QUANTITY   | FP_ID  |  RESULT  |
```

I need to populate the `result` column by using the `Quantity` and `FP_ID` columns by concatenating the `FP_ID` value to itself, and do so as many times as the value of `QUANTITY`.

So `RESULT = FP_ID` concatenated to itself `QUANTITY` times.

If `QUANTITY` is 3 and `FP_ID` is 23 then the result should be `232323`

I need to do an insert that inserts this result for each row based on this logic.

How do I do this in SQL?

Comment: Why do you want to store it when you can calculate it in the select query.
You are unnecessarily storing redundant data.

Comment: Other stored procedures rely on views where this data is expected. Why is it redundant?

Comment: there is no need to store the data as you can always calculate it while retrieving it in select query

Comment: So if you access it from various places, every time you need to calculate that row? Why not just have it in the table?

Comment: Because you are using more space when you dont actually need to store it. and another case can be if your logic changes somewhere down the line where you cannot change all the values of the table but you can change the calculation anytime. (I am talking about a general scenario).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be computed column....

I mean I should be declared as it is based on other two columns

if you want to add after creation of table

```
ALTER TABLE tblResults
ADD Final_Result as replicate(FP_ID ,Quantity)
```

else

while creation

```
    Create table tblResults
(.......ur columns..... , Final_Result as replicate(FP_ID ,Quantity))
```

you no need to give data for this column, It will automatically loaded when the data is loaded into table "tblResults"

NOTE: If any value is null then the Final_Result value will also be NULL

Comment: Thanks koushik, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer as below:

Please execute the below query to create a `Function`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConcatenateString]
(
    @FP_ID INT,
    @QUANTITY INT
)
RETURNS
    NVARCHAR(MAX) 

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ConcatenatedString NVARCHAR(MAX), @ConvertedFP_ID NVARCHAR(100) 
    SET @ConcatenatedString =''
    SET @ConvertedFP_ID = CONVERT(varchar(100),@FP_ID)

    WHILE @QUANTITY >= 1
        BEGIN
            SELECT @ConcatenatedString  = @ConcatenatedString+@ConvertedFP_ID
            SET @QUANTITY = @QUANTITY - 1
        END

    RETURN @ConcatenatedString
END
GO
```

And you can call the `Function` in the `INSERT script`:

```
INSERT INTO tblResults(DEL_ID,CP_ID,ID,QUANTITY,FP_ID,RESULT)
VALUES(1,2,3,4,5,(SELECT dbo.ConcatenateString(4,5) AS ConcatnatedValue))
```

Comment: Hi, that would work if I simply wanted the value of quantity multiplied by FP_ID but what i need is _FP_ID_ concatenate to itself _quantity_ times. I will edit my question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks Bala, is this the same as replicate() though?

Comment: @JackReilly, my answer is different from replicate(). But replicate() is the best choice. I wasn't aware of replicate and learnt it now!